# How to set GPG cache ttl in a shell script?

Tags: gpg, cache, gpg-agent

How to set `gpg-agent --no-allow-external-cache --default-cache-ttl 10 --max-cache-ttl 20`  in a shell script? After I issue the command, it gives `gpg-agent[4869]: gpg-agent running and available` but the cache ttl values are not changed. I verified it by `gpgconf --list-options gpg-agent | grep cache` as well as actually do a --decrypt and the key is still cached after 30 seconds.

I know that web resources suggest changing these configurations in the file `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`. I am not sure why I do not have that file. Even I am root, I cannot open `vi /root/S.gpg-agent` file. Anyway, I do not prefer changing these settings in the configuration file. I prefer to have different Cache TTL for different --decrypt. So It has to be issued from the shell script.

```
# ls -al /root/.gnupg/
total 36
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Jun  2 05:51 .
drwx------ 14 root root 4096 Jun  2 14:18 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   24 Jun  2 03:28 .#lk0x00005558d8861f30.gentoo_bazic.26472
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   24 Jun  2 04:16 .#lk0x0000556c15e3ef30.gentoo_bazic.7432
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   24 Jun  1 20:45 .#lk0x00005576e9d54f30.gentoo_bazic.29752
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Jun  1 02:43 private-keys-v1.d
-rw-------  1 root root   32 Jun  1 02:43 pubring.kbx
-rw-------  1 root root  600 Jun  2 05:20 random_seed
srwx------  1 root root    0 Jun  2 05:51 S.gpg-agent
srwx------  1 root root    0 Jun  2 05:51 S.gpg-agent.browser
srwx------  1 root root    0 Jun  2 05:51 S.gpg-agent.extra
srwx------  1 root root    0 Jun  2 05:51 S.gpg-agent.ssh
-rw-------  1 root root 1200 Jun  2 03:19 trustdb.gpg
```

P.S. I know that it is possible to clear the cache by `echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent`. But this is less desirable.

Reference

https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/pgg/Caching-passphrase.html

Answer (score 1):

## agent start parameters

`gpg-agent[4869]: gpg-agent running and available`

I assume that the agent exited right away after starting, the process 4869 had a lifespan of ~1 second. Your test `gpgconf --list-options gpg-agent` did probably connect to the agent that was already running with its default configuration.

gpg-agent in general doesn't seem to be designed to change its configuration while running, at least not without clearing the cache (which is not an option).

## configuration file

You don't have the file `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` because it doesn't get created by default.

The `vi /root/S.gpg-agent` was probably a typo, meant to be `vi /root/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent`. You can't edit `S.gpg-agent` because it's a socket, not a regular file.

## manage multiple configuration files

You don't want to change these settings in the configuration file, because you want different configurations per `--decrypt`. Depending on the amount of keys or complexity of use cases, it might be an alternative for you to use different GPG home directories.

If you manage `/root/gnupg-home-1/` and `/root/gnupg-home-2/`, each directory can have its own `gpg-agent.conf` in it, each with different cache TTL values. The commands

- `gpg --homedir /root/gnupg-home-1/ --decrypt ...`
- `gpg --homedir /root/gnupg-home-2/ --decrypt ...`

would trigger the start of different agent instances, each with their own configuration.

#### test/verification

You can verify the result (like you did before) with `gpgconf`, you just need to add the `--homedir` parameter:

- `gpgconf --homedir /root/gnupg-home-1/ --list-options gpg-agent |grep cache`
- `gpgconf --homedir /root/gnupg-home-2/ --list-options gpg-agent |grep cache`

#### access limitation

If root's umask doesn't prevent access to group and others already, these directories should be created with `mkdir --mode=700 <directoryname>`.

#### cleanup

Is it necessary to kill the agents after using?

From a security perspective this shouldn't be necessary, if the caching is implemented properly and the configured TTL is rather short.

From a system maintenance perspective, on a server with potentially high uptime it's a good idea to kill the agent processes, when they are not needed anymore. Otherwise the amount of unused agent processes might increase too much.

From a software state perspective, it would be inconsistent to delete the directory and keep the agent process. In my tests (gpg-agent version 2.2.35) the agent process disappeared automatically after deleting the directory. But i couldn't find anything about this in the man page, so i don't know why this happened and how reliable this is.

Depending on the use case and how your script is implemented, there might be a risk of unintended reuse of an old configuration, if the agent process is still alive after the directory has been deleted. Such a bug can be avoided by using unique directory names (eg. by using `uuidgen`).

Comment: Nice. It works perfectly. Adding `mkdir -m 700 ~/gnupg-home-1` would make it more complete. So, having a configuration file `~/gnupg-home-1/gpg-agent.conf` is the only way. We cannot pass the options to gpg-agent. After creating two more agents, may I ask how should I clean up after use? Do I need to "kill" the extra agents? Or just `rm -r` the gnupg-home directories? Thank you.

Comment: @midnite i added more information, mostly about cleanup.