# Security concerns for gpg-agent caching the passphrase?

Tags: security, gpg, cache, gpg-agent

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/pgg/Caching-passphrase.html

> When using GnuPG (gpg) as the PGP scheme, we recommend using a program called gpg-agent for entering and caching passphrases.
>
> Actually, gpg-agent does not cache passphrases but private keys. On the other hand, from a user’s point of view, this technical difference isn’t visible.

https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html

> --default-cache-ttl n
>
> ```
> Set the time a cache entry is valid to n seconds. The default is 600 seconds. Each time a cache entry is accessed, the entry’s timer is reset. To set an entry’s maximum lifetime, use max-cache-ttl. Note that a cached passphrase may not be evicted immediately from memory if no client requests a cache operation. This is due to an internal housekeeping function which is only run every few seconds.
> ```
>
> --max-cache-ttl n
>
> ```
> Set the maximum time a cache entry is valid to n seconds. After this time a cache entry will be expired even if it has been accessed recently or has been set using gpg-preset-passphrase. The default is 2 hours (7200 seconds).
> ```

As the private keys are present in the RAM for 10 minutes (600 seconds) or even up to 2 hours, will this pose a security concern? If GPG is having these defaults, does GPG have any measures to secure the private keys (e.g. encrypted)?

In addition to the risk of RAM data being extracted, there is a huge risk of [Evil Maid Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evil_maid_attack), while shortening or disabling the cache seems not easy. (Please refer to [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/704689/150246) about this.)

Comment: I’m probably missing something, but it’s not clear to me how the cache increases the risk associated with an evil maid attack. Would you mind enlightening me?

Comment: @StephenKitt - May be I did not make it clear. Or may be I used the wrong term. While the GPG is unlocked as well as the PC is unlocked, everyone gets physical access to the PC can reveal the GPG secrets.